# MVVM реализация "сцепления" grid'ов

Tags: wpf, mvvm, drag-n-drop

Скажите как мне лучше сделать при помощи mvvm такой drag'n'drop, который бы цеплял пользовательский контрол к пользовательскому контролу? В принципе как передвигать их по отдельности и обновлять модель я представляю примерно, но вот как хранить кто с кем крепится не понятно, чтобы если была бы цепочка из шести контролов она вся передвигалась.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А отцеплять можно?

Comment: Если в идеале, то наверное можно )

Comment: Я просто такого не видел нигде, поэтому пытаюсь сообразить, как должно выглядеть. Есть где то примеры, визуальные хотя бы?

Comment: @Monk ну что то очень отдалёно напоминает соединение блоков в scratch.